# Python function to return index of a n dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a function that finds the position of a class in a n dimensional array, and another function that takes that value and transforms it (or at least tries to) into an index that can be used to access and return that class.

```
def get_class(condition1, condition2):
    key = ""
    if(condition1):
        key += "1 "
    else:
        key += "0 "
    if(condition2):
        key += "1 "
    else:
        key += "0 "
    key = get_key(key)

    return classes[key]
```

It works by just adding up a string as it goes along, with each 1 meaning moving in a particular axis across the array.

The function that translates this into a index:

```
def get_key(value):
    key = value.split()
    for character in key:
        character = int(character)
        print(type(character))

    return key
```

It's supposed to convert the strings into ints and then return a position on the array, but all I get is this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Is there a better way to do this, or what am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Sample Data:

condition1 = True
condition2 = False

classes = [[6, 8], [21, 754]]

expected outcome : 21, with the key [1][0]

Comment: The question is not clear enough to attempt debugging.  In the first function, what is `classses` ?  And the error being shown must be coming from the first function.

Comment: `key = value.split()` means that `key` is a list of strings (you never modified it in `get_key` before returning it), so what is `classes[key]` supposed to do? You are trying to use a list of strings as an index, which is why you are getting that error.

Comment: Thanks for providing the sample data. Just 1 more thing, what should be the expected output from your code with above sample daqa.

Comment: Thanks for providing the expected output. Now it is clear what you ant to do. Please check the answer below and let me know if it works for you or if you have any doubts/queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything fine except for a small mistake.

In the `get_key` function, you are trying to convert and print integer vale.
But while returning the value, you are returning variable `key`

See that your variable `key` has the value returned from `value.split()`.  So the value in `key` is a list and you are returning that that list.

Now for accessing the `classses` list, you need proper integer indexes but instead you are passing this list as index.

Hence the error.

Now the solution part:

```
def get_class(condition1, condition2):
    key = ""
    if(condition1):
        key += "1 "
    else:
        key += "0 "
    if(condition2):
        key += "1 "
    else:
        key += "0 "
    key = get_key(key)

    return classes[key[0]][key[1]]


def get_key(value):
    key = value.split()
    int_list = []
    for character in key:
        character = int(character)
        print(type(character))

        int_list.append(character)
    return int_list
```

The above solution is made by modifying your code.

But it can be done more easily and clearly if you want to see that:

```
def get_class(condition1, condition2):
    if(condition1):
        key1 = 1
    else:
        key1 = 0

    if(condition2):
        key2 = 1
    else:
        key2 = 0

    return classes[key1][key2]
```

This will yied the same output as expected, but if you have any specific requirement to implement it in different functions and store key as string then you can go ahead with previous code.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. That solution is a lot better than what I was trying to do

Comment: Great. Please don't forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it helps.  Happy coding. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `key` string is not updated in the `get_key()` function. You are correctly splitting up the key in integers, but you are not using these integers.

If your input key is "1 0", then you also return "1 0" and the program crashes when you call `classes[key]` or `classes["1 0"]`.

Edit: As long as you're limited to 2 dimensional arrays you could use:

```
def get_key(value):
    key = value.split()
    for character in key:
        yield int(character)

def get_class(condition1, condition2):
    key = ""
    if(condition1):
        key += "1 "
    else:
        key += "0 "
    if(condition2):
        key += "1 "
    else:
        key += "0 "

    x, y = get_key(key)
    return classes[x][y]
```

If more dimensions are added, you will need to specify more return values from `get_key()`, but I don't know how to make this generic.
I hope this helps.

Comment: How would I use those integers and return them in a useful way?

Answer (score -1):

According to your code, `key` is of type list when reaching `return classes[key]`:

```
>>> key = "10"
>>> key.split()
['10']
```

This results in

```
>>> classes = [[6, 8], [21, 754]]
>>> classes [key]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

EDIT: You can solve it by storing the indices in `get_class` function as integers in a list.

```
classes = [[6, 8], [21, 754]]
keys = [1, 0]
for key in keys:
    classes = classes[key]
print( "%s" % classes )
```

Comment: How would I convert it to an index that I can use?

Comment: The sample you are considering is not correct. The inpyt string formed would be `1 0 `. Please cross check the answers before posting. It might lead to more doubts than solving the  problems.

Comment: @Prashnat Kumar: My EDIT clearly states that get_class needs to store the indices in a list rather than a string. So there is no string involved in my suggestion at all. Code sample can be copy+pasted and runs fine. Can you elaborate why you downvoted ?

Comment: The string that you are considering for splitting, i.e., `"10`" is not correct. It would be "`1 0 `".

Comment: Ah, i see. You are right. Instead of `key = "10"` i should've used `key = "1 0"`. Nevertheless, the Explanation is correct (exception occurs due to `key` is of type `list`). Anyway, my solution is able to `find the position of a class in a n dimensional array` as stated in the question and does not focus on 2 dimensional arrays.

Comment: Great . Cheers (Y).